Spring Boot @PrePersist Listener: "this.partido" is null
I'm a beginner in Spring and I'm trying to use a @PrePersist listener to validate a Partido entity before it is saved to the database. However, I keep encountering the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "es.mde.repositorios.Partido.getCampo()" because "this.partido" is null.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my current code:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class PartidoListener {

    @Autowired
    private PartidoDAO partidoDAO; 

    @PrePersist
    public void validacionPartido(Partido partido) {
        System.err.println("punto de fallo: 1");
        Long partidoCampoId = partido.getCampo().getId();
        LocalDateTime partidoCuando = partido.getCuando();
        System.err.println("datos de partido: " + partidoCampoId + ", " + partidoCuando );
        System.err.println("punto de fallo: 2");
        try {
            List<Partido> partidosCoincidentes = partidoDAO.findAll()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(p -> p.getCuando().equals(partidoCuando))
                    .filter(p -> p.getCampo().getId().equals(partidoCampoId))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.err.println("punto de fallo: 3");
            boolean valido = partidosCoincidentes.isEmpty();
            System.err.println("punto de fallo: 4");
            System.err.println("partido es valido: " + valido);
            System.err.println("punto de fallo: 5");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}

Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "es.mde.repositorios.Partido.getCampo()" because "this.partido" is null

Additional Information:

I have annotated my Partido entity with @EntityListeners(PartidoListener.class).
The Partido class has a Campo field, which is another entity.
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue? If you need more information or code snippets, please let me know.

Thank you!
I expected the @PrePersist listener to validate the Partido entity before it gets saved to the database by checking for conflicts based on the Campo and Cuando fields. I tried printing debug statements to identify where the issue occurs. It appears the error happens when trying to access the Campo or Cuando fields of the Partido entity, indicating that the Partido entity itself is null at this point.
I understand that retrieving all records and comparing them in memory is not efficient. I'm open to suggestions for improving this, such as defining a unique constraint in the database.
Note: This is not my final code. I am just trying to understand how to write a @PrePersist listener with a validation method. Once I understand how to do this with one example, I will be able to implement it for other entities as well.
EDIT:
Partido.class is like that:
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTIDOS")
@EntityListeners(PartidoListener.class)
public class Partido {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true)  
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAMPO")
    private Campo campo;
    private LocalDateTime cuando;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = 
    Puntuacion.class, mappedBy = "partido")
    private Collection<Puntuacion> puntuaciones = new 
    ArrayList<>();

    ...
}

Campo.class is:
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAMPOS")
public class Campo {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true)  
    private Long id;
    
    private String nombre, provincia;
    private float valorCampo, valorSlope;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = 
    Jugador.class, mappedBy = "campo")
    private Collection<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = 
    Partido.class, mappedBy = "campo")
    private Collection<Partido> partidos = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}


You haven't set the relations correctly (at least that is what it looks like). Post your entity. Also retrieving everything and compare isn't going to be very efficient. If you want unique combinations define a unique constraint in the database to handle that.

Solution:
I found the solution to my problem. It involved a couple of changes:

Injecting the DAO in the Listener
Instead of trying to inject the DAO directly into the listener, I used a static variable and a setter method with @Autowired. This way, the DAO gets properly initialized.
 @Component
 public class PartidoListener {

     private static PartidoDAO partidoDAO;

     @Autowired
     public void init(PartidoDAO partidoDAO) {
         PartidoListener.partidoDAO = partidoDAO;
     }
 }
 ...


Configuring @ComponentScan
I realized that the package where my listener was located needed to be included in the @ComponentScan annotation. I had @EnableJpaRepositories configured, but @ComponentScan was missing.


With these changes, my @PrePersist listener started working correctly, and I no longer encountered the NullPointerException.
Thank you to everyone who helped point me in the right direction!

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "es.mde.repositorios.Partido.getCampo()" because "this.partido" is null

I haven't been able to exactly reproduce the error above, but if you follow the approach below, you should not encounter it again.
You've stumbled upon multiple unrelated problems.

I could not get this injection to work. You would need constructor injection, but even this would fail because of circular dependencies, since you need the DAO inside the listener. I would recommend using a service, which would in turn use the repository / DAO. You would not save using directly the DAO, but using the service.
@Component
public class PartidoListener {

   @Autowired
   private PartidoDAO partidoDAO; 

}



@Service
public class PartidoService {

   PartidoDAO partidoDAO;

   public PartidoService(PartidoDAO partidoDAO) {
       this.partidoDAO = partidoDAO;
   }

}


RDBMS date-time truncation. You have used LocalDateTime as the type for cuando variable. LocalDateTime has nanosecond precision, but you are not guaranteed to get that in your RDBMS. Because of the truncation, the equals comparison will never work, even if exactly the same date has been used initially. In order to effectively compare, you can choose a range comparison.
public static boolean timesAreClose(LocalDateTime first, LocalDateTime second)
{
   long between = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(first, second);
   return between <= 2; // or any number of minutes
}


Performance, loading everything into memory. Rather than do a findAll, you can use Spring Data APIs to filter the data already in the database, rather than in-memory. On top of that, you don't even need to retrieve the conflicting records, unless you want to display them.


On top of the default JpaRepository methods provided by Spring, you can define your own. Here I compare the cuando time, to be within a range; and the campo to be equal. I have provided two versions, one which retrieves the records and another that just counts them.
@Repository
public interface PartidoDAO extends JpaRepository<Partido, Long> {

    List<Partido> findAllByCuandoBetweenAndCampoEquals(LocalDateTime lower, LocalDateTime upper, Campo campo);
    long countByCuandoBetweenAndCampoEquals(LocalDateTime lower, LocalDateTime upper, Campo campo);

}

So, the three approaches in the following code, ultimately do the same thing.
public boolean validate(Partido partido) {
    System.out.println("punto de fallo: 1");
    long partidoCampoId = partido.getCampo().getId();
    LocalDateTime partidoCuando = partido.getCuando();
    System.out.println("datos de partido: " + partidoCampoId + ", " + partidoCuando );
    System.out.println("punto de fallo: 2");
    try {
        List<Partido> partidosCoincidentes = partidoDAO.findAll()
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> timesAreClose(p.getCuando(), partidoCuando))
                .filter(p -> p.getCampo().getId().equals(partidoCampoId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("punto de fallo: 3");
        System.out.println("Partido " + partido.getId() + " with localdatetime " + partidoCuando);
        System.err.println("Got conflict " + partidosCoincidentes);
        boolean valido = partidosCoincidentes.isEmpty();
        List<Partido> throughRepo = partidoDAO.findAllByCuandoBetweenAndCampoEquals(partidoCuando.minusMinutes(2L), partidoCuando.plusMinutes(2L), partido.getCampo());
        System.out.println("Partidos through repo " + throughRepo);
        long countConflicts = partidoDAO.countByCuandoBetweenAndCampoEquals(partidoCuando.minusMinutes(2L), partidoCuando.plusMinutes(2L), partido.getCampo());
        System.out.println("Got number of conflicts " + countConflicts);
        return valido;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

Another improvement you can make is to use a logger, rather than use System.out and System.err
